# Create Tables belonging to different problems with same name in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have been involved in mysql programming a bit. There we can create separate databases under the same user for different projects.e.g.(college database, hospital database) How can we achieve that in oracle sql? And I want a command line solution.I.e. sqlplus.
The problem appearing in sqlplus is that once two tables of different databases appear having the same name, error is delivered. What to do to have a different environment for each project under the same user alone?

Comment: You either want separate schemas on the same Oracle server, or multiple servers running (one per database).  It sort of depends what you mean by "database".

Comment: I want seperate schemas in one server itself. I also found that for one user I would have one schema only in oracle or something like that. Correct me if I'm wrong. But I would want different schemas under the same user only

Comment: . . In Oracle, a schema (pretty much) is a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be bit confusing to start with Oracle RDBMS when you got used to MySQL world.
A user in MySQL doesn't own DB objects: tables/views/etc, all DB objects belong to database. In Oracle all objects belong to schemes (synonym for user, showing that this user owns DB objects).

I want to show you different approaches in MySQL and in Oracle for the same tasks:

set current database (MySQL)/ set current schema (Oracle)

MySQL:

```
use db_name;
```

Oracle:

```
alter session set current_schema = schema_name;
```

Create fully qualified table:

MySQL:

```
create table db_name.table_name ...
```

Oracle:

```
create table schema_name.table_name ...
```

Select from another's DB/schema table

MySQL:

```
select * from database_name.table_name where ...
```

Oracle:

```
select * from user_owning_table.table_name where ...
```

So you basically want to create another Oracle schema (let's call it "hospital") for your new project:

```
create user hospital identified by "<password>";

create table hospital.employee( ... );
create table college.employee ( ... );

grant select, insert, update, delete on hospital.employee to human_user;
grant select, insert, update, delete on college.employee to human_user;

sqlplus human_user@your_tnsnames_alias
SQL> insert into hospital.employee(...) values(...);
SQL> insert into college.employee(...) values(...);
```

Comment: So basically we create a user~schema for a particular project and then if we want to add more users to the project, we create users and grant privileges. The original user~schema is the sysdba. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You may also want to create roles for different projects or different groups of users, then grant privileges on objects to those roles and finally grant roles to users. So that you will grant privileges to roles for new objects only ones and then you will have to grant a corresponding role to new users. In order to create users you need DBA privilege.